# Delete Snapshots of 30 days older from HBASE Using Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, hbase, hadoop2

I want to delete 30 days older snapshots from `HBASE` using shell script. I have written below function but the function will be deleting all snapshots. 30 days older logic also need to be implemented.

```
deleteSnapshot() {

  echo -e "list_snapshots '${NAMESPACE}_${TABLE}'" | hbase shell -n | grep ''${NAMESPACE}'_'${TABLE}'' 2>/dev/null

  local RET=$?

  if [ ${RET} -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Deleting Snapshot ${NAMESPACE}_${TABLE}"
      echo -e "delete_snapshot '${NAMESPACE}_${TABLE}'" | hbase shell -n 2>/dev/null
      echo "Successfully deleted Snapshot ${NAMESPACE}_${TABLE}"
  fi
}
```

Help need on that.

Comment: You should tell us what's not working with what you did already.

Answer (score 2):

You can append the time stamp to the the snapshot name and apply a regex to match only the snapshots that are older than 30 days.

You can refer the document:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cm_bdr_managing_hbase_snapshots.html#concept_aqd_sry_bp

Answer (score 1):

### The quick and dirty way to delete multiple snapshots at once:

If our snapshot name was: **table_name_snapshot_20190701**

```
delete_all_snapshot 'table_name_snapshot_201907.*'
```

This deletes anything from July. The `.` in the name is used as a cutoff for the rest of the snapshot name (which we've replaced with a wildcard `*`)